# How to get tools to show up in Pivot?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a problem while using **Pivot** in **XAML WP8**. It seems that the second **Pivot** in `SIGN UP` doesn't want to show any of the tools I have given, like the button, etc.

I recently modified the grid so I think you should be check it too.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Help_.MainPage"
    xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="AppbarLogin" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/check.png" Text="sign in" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="about" Click="ApplicationBarMenuItem_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>

        <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="AppbarSignup" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/check.png" Text="sign up" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="about" Click="ApplicationBarMenuItem_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>

        <Style x:Key="GambarHeader" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="46"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="229*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="64*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image 
                                    Source="/Assets/Gambar/help_text_comp.png"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Margin="20,12,0,0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                    Width="120" />

                            </Grid>

                            <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Help_" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>

    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#14b29b">

        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Title="" Style="{StaticResource GambarHeader}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource SmallSizeHeader}" SelectionChanged="SelectionPivot_Changed">

            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="SIGN IN" Margin="12,28,12,-61" Height="513" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <Grid Height="513" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <TextBox 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email" Width="446" Foreground="Gray" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_2" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus_2" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Grid Margin="0,85,10,236">
                        <TextBox x:Name="PasswordWatermark" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" LostFocus="PasswordLostFocus" Opacity="0" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" GotFocus="PasswordGotFocus"     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="SigninFacebook" Content="Sign in with Facebook" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,317,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" Click="SigninFacebook_Click"/>

                </Grid>

            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="SIGN UP" Margin="12,28,12,-61" Height="457" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button Content="11" />
            </phone:PivotItem>

        </phone:Pivot>

    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Where's your ItemsPanel?